# How to handle a POST request from a Django form loaded via a custom template tag?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I added a Django form to my Bootstrap nav bar to be included on every page, and it renders as it should with the appropriate values.  The form was added using an inclusion_tag.  However, I'm now at a loss as to how to handle the request from the form. Upon submission, whichever page the user was on should reload with updated content from the form submission.  For more context, see my earlier question: [How to place a django form in a nav bar so that it appears on every page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60660373/how-to-place-a-django-form-in-a-nav-bar-so-that-it-appears-on-every-page/60663246#60663246)

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question (again). To handle a request from a form that appears on every page and loaded via a custom template tag, create a url path and corresponding view -- e.g. '/form-submission/' and form_submission_view. In the view, handle the form processing logic as you normally would for a POST request, but then return a redirection back to whatever page the user was on when the form was submitted, like so:

```
return redirect(request.POST.get('path'))
```